# HTML CSS How to change border shape

Tags: html, css, border, center

I am designing a website and for the main title, I would like it to say "Definitive Apps" With a border all around at and even distance from the text the entire way.

This is the code I am using for my border

```
#home-banner h1 {
   border-width: 5px;
   border-style: solid;
   text-align:center;
}
```

However, this gives this result:
[image: Result1]

I then tried to change the width but that gave me this result:

```
#home-banner h1 {
   border-width: 5px;
   border-style: solid;
   width: 500px;
   text-align:center;
}
```

[image: Result2]

I would like an even border with the text in the centre of the page. Is this possible?

Comment: Try adding `margin: auto;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to define `width`, use `display: table`.

```css
#home-banner h1 {
   border-width: 5px;
   border-style: solid;
   display: table;
   margin: auto;
   text-align:center;  
   padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-banner">
  <h1>
    Heading 1
  </h1>
</div>
```

If the width is fixed (500px), just add `margin: auto;` to your code.

```css
#home-banner h1 {
   border-width: 5px;
   border-style: solid;
   width: 200px;
   margin: auto;
   text-align:center;  
   padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-banner">
  <h1>
    Heading 1
  </h1>
</div>
```